# ʃɔː can you pls help me what word is this po?

Tags: english

/ʃɔː/    can you pls help me what word is this po?

Comment: The only English word po I know is in the term "po' boy", a kind of sandwich, meaning "poor boy" as pronounced in an r-less dialect of English.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Po%27_boy

Comment: "Shaw", "Shah", "Hsiao", "sure", "shore" are all candidates. Context may tell.

Comment: @user6726 Who on earth would pronounce _hsiao_ (=_xiao_) as /ʃɔː/? Presumably they’d pronounce _shower_ the same, I suppose?

Comment: It's is one adaptation of Chinese pronunciation into American English. That's how she says it. Shower = [ʃæwɹ̩], two syllables.

Answer (score 4):

**/ʃɔː/** is the IPA transcription of the word '[shore](http://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/shore)' in *non-rhotic accents*. Sometimes '[sure](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sure)' is also pronounced as /ʃɔː/.

/ʃ/ is called '[voiceless postalveolar fricative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_postalveolar_fricative)'. It is the *shhh* sound present in the beginning of words like shy, shore, she etc.

/ɔː/ is called '[open-mid back rounded vowel or low-mid back rounded vowel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_rounded_vowel)'. It is present in words like north, law, thought etc.

In *rhotic accents*, the /r/ sound is always pronounced so /ʃɔː/ in rhotic accents would be pronounced as /ʃɔːr/ (with 'r' sound).

In non-rhotic accents, the /r/ sound is not pronounced unless it precedes a vowel sound so /ʃɔːr/ becomes /ʃɔː/.

Generally, in General American the 'r' in /ɔːr/ is pronounced while in RP, the 'r' is not pronounced.

Comment: It’s also _shaw_ in both rhotic and non-rhotic.

Comment: Good point. @JanusBahsJacquet